# Can't get a key of an object from Firebase in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to create a simple app while learning Angular. The app is simple, getting a list of employees on the homepage and viewing their detailed information by clicking on the employee.

The project has 2 components and 1 service: **TableViewComponent**, **ViewProfileComponent**, and **DataService**. With routing on the homepage, the TableViewComponent is shown by default. When an employee is clicked, the browser navigates to 'example.com/view/:id' and ViewProfileComponent.

So here is the problem. When the browser is on the "homepage" the DataService works perfectly. Once the URL is switched to '/view/:id', the DataService 
 function "**private _findEmployeeById()**" returns **undefined**, instead of the key of the object I need. Once again, it works on the homepage!

I have been struggling with this one for a few days and can't make it work. I have seen the Angular Tour of Heroes and in my opinion, it's almost the same, so that's why I can't find the problem.

Here is the link to the full project on [Github](https://github.com/d3n1el1/nc-final-project), maybe it will be easier to understand the problem.

```
private _findEmployeeById(id: number): string {
    const ref = this.db.database.ref();
    let key: string;

    // Key returns undefined, when the URL is example.com/view/id
    // Works properly on home page (when the URL is example.com)
    ref.child('employee').orderByChild('id').equalTo(id).once('value', snap => {
      snap.forEach(data => {
        key = data.key;
      });
    });

    return key;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your culprit:

```
ref.child('employee').orderByChild('id').equalTo(id).once('value', snap => {
    snap.forEach(data => {
    key = data.key;
    });
});
```

This bit of code is asynchronous which means it won't get processed right away. In fact it will kick off the request but then happily move on to the next thing that it can process, which in your case is the `return key`. When it gets to `return key` the part that actually determines the value of key hasn't yet been processed so you get undefined.

I think you'd probably want to refactor your method to look something like this:

```
private _findEmployeeById(id: number): Promise<string> {
  const ref = this.db.database.ref();
  let key: string;

  return ref.child('employee').orderByChild('id').equalTo(id).once('value').then(snap => {
    snap.forEach(data => {
      key = data.key;
    })
    return key;
  })
}
```

This says, return the function that promises to return a value, then return the value when it is resolved. You'll notice I updated the function signature to a promise that ultimately resolves to a string. This will have cascading implications for any consumer of your method.

Instead of:

`const key = this._findEmployeeById(removeEmployee.id);`

You'll need to do

```
this._findEmployeeById(removeEmployee.id).then(key => {
   console.log(key);
})
```

I'll also add I've never done anything with firebase so there might be a better more firebasey way to handle this but that's the crux of your problem. Worth a watch if you're unfamiliar with the event loop:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: First of all, thank you! That was the problem. The reason why I didn't think of that, because everything worked on the homepage, but not on the /view/id page.

The next thing I occurred, that the function call inside the ViewProfileComponent is resolving earlier than the function inside DataService. I have pushed a new commit to the Github (the link is in my question post). So, I am again getting undefined inside that component. I am returning a Promise, but why it's resolving too early?

Comment: @D3N1EL, I have made a pull request to your repository along with some hopefully helpful information. Feel free to comment on there if you have any questions and if you think this answered your question please mark my answer as correct. Happy coding!